# Symfony. How to build the form?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-4.2

How to implement the form, that accepts the following JSON-Object?
I have defined no models, because I don't need them. The data are sent

```
{
  "type_of_error": "logic error",
  "severity": "normal",
  "what_did_you_do": "something",
  "what_happened": "blue screen",
  "which_result": "full satisfaction",
  "requests": [
    {
      "url": "/api/v1/agent/statistic"
    }
  ]
}
```

I already have begun to build the form:

```
class ErrorReportFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type_of_error', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => '',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank()
                ]
            ])
            ->add('severity', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => '',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank()
                ]
            ])
            ->add('what_did_you_do', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => '',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank()
                ]
            ])
            ->add('what_happened', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => '',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ]
            ])
            ->add('which_result', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => '',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ]
            ])
            ->add('requests', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type'   => RequestsFormType::class,
            ])
        ;
    }
```

And I have defined RequestsFormType like this. What is here wrong? It looks, as if RequestsFormType would not be accepted.

```
class RequestsFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('url', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => '',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank()
                ]
            ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try with using a CollectionType.

See here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

```
$builder->add('requests', CollectionType:class, [
    'entry_type'   => YourCustomType::class,
]);
```

YourCustomType :

```
class YourCustomType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('url', TextType::class, []);
        $builder->add('method', TextType::class, []);
        $builder->add('timestamp', DateTimeType::class, []);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Requests::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to define url, method and timestamp?

Comment: In Collectiontype give the argument :
`'entry_type'   => YourCustomType::class,`
Create a custom form and in the builder add url, method and timestamp

Comment: should I define an extra class? Is there no another solution?
and how to create a custom form  in the buildForm-method?

Comment: Yes, you should create a custom type, like RequestsType and in Form builder, add your parameters : url, method and timestamp. I don't know if there is another solution. This one should fits your need

Comment: Ok, it looks like a form in another form.

Comment: How to create YourCustomType in the same php-file?
I don't want to create an extra file with the class YourCustomType

Comment: The best practice is to create a separate file for your Forms. Have a look at the documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#form-creating-form-classes
Create your separate file and then include it in your controller :
`$form = $this->createForm(XXXType::class, $xxxx);`

Comment: Yes, but I can not say entry_type'   => $form.
It doesn't work

Comment: You should have two Form files : XXXXType.php (type_of_error, severity, etc..) and RequestsType.php (url, timestamp etc..). In XXXXType you are building your form. So add the CollectionType and in parameter `entry_type` give your second form `RequestsType:class`. And in your controller create the $form like I said before

Comment: It doesn't work. I receive an error: The form may not have additional fields (Dieses Formular sollte keine zusätzlichen Felder enthalten.)

Comment: Could you update your post to add what you did please ?

Comment: `'allow_add'` => true was missing. It works now, Thanks!